# Error in the installation step of the pyreaddbc library

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert .dbc files to .cvs using the package [pyreadbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyreaddbc/), but I encounter an error right after running: pip install pyreaddbc.

Error appearing: Error: Failed building wheel for pyreaddbc
Failed to build pyreaddbc
Error: Could not build wheels for pyreadbc, which is requiered to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Can anyone help me resolve it? Or indicate another way to do the conversion? I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages actually contain more informations than what you have shown.
The problem is that `pyreaddbc` contains C modules and requires a C compilation framework compatible with your Python interpretor on your machine. If you do not have, the compilation will fail. Furthermore, the PyPI directory only contains a source archive (tgz file) and a Linux wheel, and pyreaddbc only claims to be a alpha level software: this is a hint that it is not intented to be run on a Windows system and is not tested there.

I have tried to go one step further and build a wheel on my Windows system (with MSVC installed...): it failed because at least one C file includes unistd.h, which is a Unix thing.

TL/DR: pyreaddbc is only supported on a Linux or Unix-like system. You cannot build it from source on Windows. At least without fixing a number of things in the source to make it portable on Windows...